# Loops through an array, only returning based on a specific criteria?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops

I am trying to figure out where I am going wrong with this. I am doing a self-taught program and seem to be stuck every now and then.

"Write a program that loops through the given array of objects. If the user is married, print their name to the screen."

---

```js
const users = [
  {
    'first_name': 'Homer',
    'last_name' : 'Simpson',
    'dob': '03/19/195-', 
    'married': true, 
  }, 
  {
    'first_name': 'Marge',
    'last_name': 'Simpson',
    'dob': '05/12/56',
    'married': true,
  }, 
  {
    'first_name': 'Lisa',
    'last_name': 'Simpson',
    'dob': '04/19/87',
    'married': false,
  }, 
]

for ([i] in users) {
 if (users['married'] = true)
    console.log(users['first_name'])
  }
```

---

**The expected return should be**

Homer

Marge

**but I am only getting**

undefined

undefined

undefined

Comment: `=` is assingment. `==` or `===` is comparison. Your loop doesn't look right either.

Comment: If you think any of the responses has answered your question, then consider marking it as accepted for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const users = [
  {
    'first_name': 'Homer',
    'last_name' : 'Simpson',
    'dob': '03/19/195-', 
    'married': true, 
  }, 
  {
    'first_name': 'Marge',
    'last_name': 'Simpson',
    'dob': '05/12/56',
    'married': true,
  }, 
  {
    'first_name': 'Lisa',
    'last_name': 'Simpson',
    'dob': '04/19/87',
    'married': false,
  }, 
]

for (i in users) {
  if (users[i]['married'] === true)
     console.log(users[i]['first_name'])
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ([i] in users) {
 if (users['married'] = true)
    console.log(users['first_name'])
}
```

**There are two issues with your `if` statement:**

**1)** By `users['married']`, you are trying to access `married` property of `users` but it doesn't exist, `users` is an array.

**2)** You are using the assignment operator `=` for comparision. You should use `==` or `===` for comparison.

[for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) iterates over enumerable properties of an object. Since `users` is an array, we are iterating over the indices of the array. So to access values at a particular index, we use `users[i]`.

I'll also remove the unnecessary brackets around `i`.

**Fixed code:**

```
  for (i in users) {
    if (users[i]['married'] == true)
      console.log(users[i]['first_name'])
  }
```

**Demo:**

```js
const users = [
  {
    'first_name': 'Homer',
    'last_name' : 'Simpson',
    'dob': '03/19/195-', 
    'married': true, 
  }, 
  {
    'first_name': 'Marge',
    'last_name': 'Simpson',
    'dob': '05/12/56',
    'married': true,
  }, 
  {
    'first_name': 'Lisa',
    'last_name': 'Simpson',
    'dob': '04/19/87',
    'married': false,
  }, 
]

for (i in users) {
  if (users[i]['married'] == true)
    console.log(users[i]['first_name'])
}
```

Comment: what about `for ([i] in users) {`? Any words?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly - I added explanation for `for...in` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[].forEach`

```js
const users = [{
    'first_name': 'Homer',
    'last_name': 'Simpson',
    'dob': '03/19/195-',
    'married': true,
  },
  {
    'first_name': 'Marge',
    'last_name': 'Simpson',
    'dob': '05/12/56',
    'married': true,
  },
  {
    'first_name': 'Lisa',
    'last_name': 'Simpson',
    'dob': '04/19/87',
    'married': false,
  },
]

users.forEach(function (user) {
  if (user.married === true) {
    console.log(user.first_name)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

***check this short and sweet version***

```js
const users = [{
    'first_name': 'Homer',
    'last_name': 'Simpson',
    'dob': '03/19/195-',
    'married': true,
  },
  {
    'first_name': 'Marge',
    'last_name': 'Simpson',
    'dob': '05/12/56',
    'married': true,
  },
  {
    'first_name': 'Lisa',
    'last_name': 'Simpson',
    'dob': '04/19/87',
    'married': false,
  },
]

users.forEach(user => {
if(user.married) console.log(user.first_name)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

`for/in` [loops through the properties of an object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp), while you want to loop through the objects themselves...

```
const users = [
  {
    'first_name': 'Homer',
    'last_name' : 'Simpson',
    'dob': '03/19/195-', 
    'married': true, 
  }, 
  {
    'first_name': 'Marge',
    'last_name': 'Simpson',
    'dob': '05/12/56',
    'married': true,
  }, 
  {
    'first_name': 'Lisa',
    'last_name': 'Simpson',
    'dob': '04/19/87',
    'married': false,
  }, 
]
for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
  {
    if(users[i]['married'] == true)
      {console.log(users[i]['first_name'])}
  }
```